# XNA list elementAt

Tags: c#, list, xna

I'm using a `List` of platforms. I need to do something like `platforms.get(i).X`
I found something like that, it's called `elementAt`, but it only allows you to do `platforms.elementAt(i).draw()`. How do I check the variables of a specific object in the list?

Comment: Need more information. What is a `platform`? The `elementAt` method of a list will return an object in the list at that index. If the object does not expose the property that you need via its interface, then you will need to alter it to do so.

Comment: Post some code. Show us what you're trying to do (in code, if possible).

Comment: In C# List<T> is indexable with `[]`, i.e., `platforms[i].X`. If you can't see properties or fields from this object reference then they are probably not using the proper protection to allow the caller to access them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access list elements with array index notation.

```
int x = platforms[i].X;
```

Comment: sorry, I realised I was an idiot. If I simply make the variable public ex: public Vector2 position; then I can type Platforms.elementAt(i).position = whatever. Thanks for the help any ways though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a delegate for something like yourlist.Exists

```
if (stringlist.Exists(
                delegate(String s)
                {
                    return (s == "what you want to be found"); //this returns true if it is found.
                }
                ))
            {
                //What you want to do if it is found.
            }
```

Lookup more info about using lists and delegates and you should stumble on a way you could use this to solve your problem.